# how to pass two values in query string when click on row of repeater?

Tags: asp.net, .net, repeater

I have a repeater. and when we click on its row its redirecting to another page along with one value. Using the code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_Tasks" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr onclick='window.location = "<%# ResolveClientUrl( "~/Detailpage.aspx?jtid=" + Eval("taskid") ) %>"' style="cursor: pointer;">
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

now there is another field that is "name" its coming through query string on this page. now i want to use this value also in tr's on click , I don't know how please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
+ Request.QueryString["name"]
```

?

Also I recommend to do that in code-behind on, say [ItemCreated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Bind With Database Field:
    "' style="cursor: pointer;">

Here is simple example to create link in DataItemTemplate of a GridView:

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Role" FieldName="Role" Name="colRole" VisibleIndex="3" Width="30px">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%# "ReceivePage.aspx?id=" + Eval("UserName") + "&b="+ Eval("Password")  %>'>link</a>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

If you want to use querystring in the binding then simply call  server side code in href..

```
 <tr onclick='window.location="<%# ResolveClientUrl( "~/Detailpage.aspx?jtid=" + Eval("taskid") + "&name=" + Request.QueryString["name"] ) %>"' style="cursor: pointer;">
```